# Поиск(where) обрезает GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Не могу понять, как сделать запрос, чтобы чертов (`WHERE genre_id = 1`) не обрезал массив в `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Общий вид таблиц:

```
idbook
book_id | genre_id
idgenre | genre
```

Вот такой запрос работает отлично:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS thisgenre,
FROM
    book
        LEFT JOIN
    genre_book ON idbook = book_id
        LEFT JOIN
    genre ON genre_id = idgenre
GROUP BY idbook
```

Выводит:

```
Триллер
Триллер,Экшн,Приключения
Триллер,Психология,Постапокалиптика,Ужасы
```

А когда я пытаюсь добавить в поисковой запрос на жанры (`WHERE genre_id = 1`):

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS thisgenre,
FROM
    book
        LEFT JOIN
    genre_book ON idbook = book_id
        LEFT JOIN
    genre ON genre_id = idgenre
WHERE genre_id = 1
GROUP BY idbook
```

Получается:

```
Триллер
Триллер
Триллер
```

Но мне нужен весь массив жанров, я его вывожу на страницу.

Comment: Может вам надо писать `LEFT JOIN
    genre ON genre_id = idgenre AND genre_id = 1` ? было бы конечно неплохо увидеть тестовые данные например в http://sqlfiddle.com/  для большего понимания структур

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставьте в выборке все жанры, что бы их захватил group_concat и отфильтруйте требуемые книги после группировки, т.е. в `having`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS thisgenre,
  FROM book
  LEFT JOIN genre_book ON idbook = book_id
  LEFT JOIN genre ON genre_id = idgenre
 GROUP BY idbook
HAVING sum(IF(genre_id=1,1,0))>0
```